# Apache RewriteRule on a URL generated by wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a URL that is generated as part of wordpress. `https://website.com/somepage?arg1=1`I want to clean this up with a rewrite rule but it is not working.

> RewriteRule ^somepage/subset/([^/]*)$ /somepage?arg1=$1 [QSA,L]

I cant get the rewrite rule to work, it keeps returning a 404 page. I am guessing this is something to doo wiith the fact that this URL doesnt exist within apache but rather php/wordpress. Is there a way for me to get around this?

The end result here is that I want

> https://website.com/somepage?arg1=1

to be rewritten to look like

> https://website.com/somepage/subset/1

Comment: Is your rule in `.htaccess` or in apache `.conf` file?

Comment: I have tried placing it in both.

Comment: I suggest you first try adding `RewriteRule ^ - [F]`, it should block **all** requests, just to determine if your rewrite rules are being executed at all

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand what you are struggling with here. Would you like to remove the query string after the */somepage* part or it is something else? In case it is something else, please provide a bit more information.

Comment: I have given an example of what I have now and what I want the URL to look like after. I have written plenty of rules in the past but they were always going to page.php?arg=1. This time I am trying to rewrite a url that is already rewritten but just has some extra args